# Is it possible to do this without JavaScript (html layout)

Tags: javascript, html

The page has the following layout:

```
<div id="main" style="min-height:500px;"> 
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
<div>
```

The main div can have a fixed height or min-height (`style="height:500px;"` or `style="min-height:375px;"`).

Is it possible to make the footer and header take as much height as they need and allow the content to take the rest `(content.height = main.height - (header.height + footer.height))` (without using JavaScript, elastic header and footer, content takes the rest)?

Comment: That my friend, is an age old problem.

Comment: Chuck Norris doesn't code JavaScript, JavaScript fixes its `this` semantics and begs Chuck Norris for forgiveness.

Comment: Chuck Norris simply types `(content.height = main.height - (header.height + footer.height))` into the plain html and it works as it should.

Comment: @Christoph Chuck Norris doesn't do anything. The HTML page just does what Chuck Norris wants to do.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it **is** possible.

HTML:

```
<div id="main"> 
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%; /* needed for #main min-height */
}

div#main {
    position: relative; /* needed for footer positioning */
    height: auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height: 500px; /* IE6: treated as min-height*/
    min-height: 500px; /* real browsers */
}

div#header {
    /* Will be as high as its content */
}

div#content {
    /* Will be displayed below #header regardless to its height */
    padding: 0px 0px 50px 0px; /* bottom padding for footer + space */
}

div#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; /* Needs to be fixed size because of #content padding-bottom */
    bottom: 0; /* stick to bottom */
}
```

This actually don't set `#content` height as you wanted, but displays everything as it should be (`#main` has expected height, `#footer` is at the bottom and doesn't cover `#content`).

Comment: in your case footer and header have a fixed height, I need them to take as much height as they need, the content of the header and footer can change and the height should as well

Comment: No, only `#foooter` has fixed height, `#header` will be as high as its content and `#content` will simply move down. Maybe I should edit comment about `#header` in CSS.

Comment: so it's not possible to have them both take as much as they need and #content the rest

Comment: You said "_is it possible to make the footer and header take as much height as they need_" - it isn't equivalent to "_not with fixed height_". In this case, when you want to `#header` and `#footer` to be elastic, maybe there's no pure CSS solution - at least I don't know it now.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found (doesn't work correctly in IE6/7)...

```
<table height="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr height="1"><td>Header goes here</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Main content goes here</td></tr>
    <tr height="1"><td>Footer goes here</td></tr>
</table>
```

The key point is setting a small height for the top and bottom rows and not setting any height for the middle row. This encourages the browser to keep the top and bottom rows as small as possible and to use the middle row for taking up any unused space. But IE6/7 ignores this and tries to evenly spread out the unused space over all 3 rows.

Still, this may be the closest you can get without using JavaScript (or adding an IE-specific CSS expression (i.e., dynamic property) of some sort, which I wouldn't recommend).

HTML tables are the only option that offers a measure of control over vertical layout (size and alignment) without using JavaScript. If that's what you need, an HTML table is the way to go. But you may be better off staying within the limitations of CSS-based layouts.

Answer (score 0):

To use simply CSS footer need to has fixed size.